What does adding Amber to fertilizer do?
When adding base components to fertilizer, what is the purpose of adding Amber? When I add a Beast Hoof, Beast Manure, or Fallen Leaves, it increases the percentages listed in soil nutrients. However, if I add amber to the fertilizer, it seems to have no effect regardless of if I add 0 Amber or 800 Amber.


It's an enhancer of the other ingredients:
https://sakuna-of-rice-and-ruin.fandom.com/wiki/Fertilizer

The fourth item you add to it is Amber; the more you put in, the more potent the effects of the leaf/kernel/root fertilizer added at this step, thus adding more nutrients to the fertilizer.

https://www.reddit.com/r/sakunaofriceandruin/comments/1bb1zce/fertilizer_guide/

The ratio between Amber and Fertilizer stats is 1 to 0.12. (200 amber at 100% to each fertilizer type will raise each fertilizer stat by 24 points).


No! You broke the streak... I was trying to answer every question from Stevoisiak about this game... even though I've never played it... because it's funny...

@Daemons - Heh. Sorry! ;) Do you own a copy btw? Or not even that? Well, maybe you'll get the next one!

No, I've just answered every question from Stevoisiak about this game so far. I didn't even know the game existed before the first question. And here's hoping!
